# html 5 and bootstrap query

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make the image responsive but the image is not getting responsive![enter image description here][1] how to sort it out the below given is the code. please do help..

```
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="main2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="main2" style="margin-left:150px;">
        <h3 style="color:white; margin-top: -44px; padding-left: 164px;">Consumer Electronics</h3>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Enterprising Solution

```
                        <!-- End of section enterprising -->



                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="pull-right">
                    <div class="col-md-10" style="margin-top:-483px; width:auto%;">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="mobile.png" alt="mobile">

            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Is the row code wrapped in a bootstrap container? Or container-fluid?

Comment: no its not wrapped in container nor container-fluid.

Comment: Look at answer below

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the bootstrap documentation, in order for any of the CSS to work it needs to be in the grid system. Which has to be wrapped in a container in order to use the grid this is why your column isn't getting properly created for the div to size to.

From bootstrap docs

Bootstrap requires a containing element to wrap site contents and house our grid system. You may choose one of two containers to use in your projects. Note that, due to padding and more, neither container is nestable.

Use .container for a responsive fixed width container.

```
<div class="container">
  ...
</div>
```

Use .container-fluid for a full width container, spanning the entire width of your viewport.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="jumboron">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10" style="margin-top:-483px;">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="mobile.png" alt="mobile">
    
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

Comment: now i am facing problem is sir the image is floating left the above is the code but the image has to be on the right hand side..

Comment: Ok now that would be done with an offset. Make sure if you are putting other content in to put it in before. Remember the bootstrap grid is based off of 12 columns. So if using md-10 you need more content on the left and the img column will move further right if no more content you will need to use an offset like changing the image to a md-4 and setting .col-md-offset-8

Comment: sir i have give image <div class="col-md-offset-6"> and the image is not floating to the right so what i have added the styles such as

Comment: <img class="img-responsive" src="mobile.png" alt="mobile"
      style="margin-top:-483px; float: right;">

Comment: can some one help me with a solution for this